# How to call a parameterized method one time to execute it automatically in multiple actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm working on an `Asp.net core 5` targeted `.net 5`.
In a `controller` I have this method :

```
    private void LoadRelatedModelProperties(ref SchoolSubjectModel model)
    {
        model.Branches = _genericRepo.Get<Branche>();
        model.Semesters = _genericRepo.Get<Semester>();
        model.FormationYears = _genericRepo.Get<FormationYear>();

    }
```

The `LoadRelatedModelProperties` is called in the most of `Actions` in the controller, so I should write the name of the method and pass the model to it in every action.

Example 1:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(SchoolSubjectModel model)
        {
           // Some logic here
            LoadRelatedModelProperties( ref model );
            return View( nameof(Edit) , model );
        }
```

Example 2:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SchoolSubjectModel model)
    {
        // Some logic here

        LoadRelatedModelProperties(ref model);
        
        return View(model);
    }
```

That's will repeated with a other actions in other controllers.

**The question:**

Is there any way or technic to call this method one time and pass the model to it from the called action in runtime ?

Comment: Well 2 things... First why are you passing SchoolSubjectModel using "ref" is this a struct or class?  Second could you post the code for the SchoolSubjectModel? Because if all it has is 3 properties you could probably construct this object inside the controller's constructor and store it in class level field

Comment: I do not think the question make any sense. The method is already called at runtime, but since it needs a parameter it cannot be called just one time.

Comment: You want to only execute LoadRelatedModelProperties once per request for the exact same model?

Comment: @Akade yeah  but I don't wanna repeat it in all actions

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with Action? What is the expected lifetime of such a model?